# C++ - Makefile Good Practice

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have a Makefile that works for how I'm using it, but will anyone tell me if what I'm doing is good practice? Or if there is a better, cleaner or more efficient way to achieve the goal I am reaching?

Here is my Makefile Code.

```
# Object files to either reference or create
OBJECTS = Proj2.o Blackjack.o Deck.o Card.o Hand.o Player.o
# The executable file that will be created
EXEC = Proj2.out
# The c++ flags to use for compilation
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
# The c++ compiler to use for compilation
CXX = g++

# This section is called on 'make'
# Will call compile, and then call clean
all: compile clean

# Perform action on all object files (May or may not exist)
# The makefile will implicitly compile all .o files needed
# Will also compile them into the EXEC file listed
compile: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)

# This section is called after compilation is completed
# This will clean all existing .o files listed in the directory
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Here is the terminal output when I call `make`.

```
g++ -Wall   -c -o Proj2.o Proj2.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Blackjack.o Blackjack.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Deck.o Deck.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Card.o Card.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Hand.o Hand.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Player.o Player.cpp
g++ -Wall -o Proj2.out Proj2.o Blackjack.o Deck.o Card.o Hand.o Player.o
rm -f *.o
```

Is it good practice to use a Makefile like this? Specifically, am I doing the cleaning part of my Makefile correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You should not make `all` depend on `clean` at all.  By doing this you are ensuring that every time you run `make`, you have to recompile everything.  If you want to do that then using `make` is itself useless: just write a shell script that compiles and links your code.

The `clean` target should be a separate target and if you want to clean your workspace you run `make clean` explicitly.

The other problem with your makefile is that the link rule lists `compile` as the target, but it builds `$(EXE)`.  It's almost never a good idea to have a rule create a file which is not exactly the target you told make it would build.  To ensure this, always use `$@` as the target to generate.  Rewrite it like this:

```
compile: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: What does the $@ and the $^ do exactly?

Comment: Yes, also, I often times will create a really clean target called "clobber". Clean might just remove the binaries for example whereas clobber might clean more such as other generated files (documentation, etc.)

Comment: $@ is an alias for your target name and $^ is an alias for the target prerequisites. Check out http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html section 10.5.3